# Cleverref when used with subcaption and minted shows "?? 1a" for clever references

Tags: subcaption, minted, cleveref, newfloat

If I combine cleverref with subcaption and minted, then `\cref{lst:subfigure}` does resolve to "?? 1a", when it should be "listing 1a". How can I fix this?

Minimal non-working example

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{cpp}
void foo() {};
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Left figure caption}
    \label{lst:foo}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{cpp}
void bar() {};
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Right figure caption}
    \label{lst:bar}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall Caption}
  \label{lst:foo-bar}
\end{listing}

\begin{itemize}
\item Overall: \cref{lst:foo-bar}
\item Foo: \cref{lst:foo}
\item Bar: \cref{lst:bar}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered version with "?? 1a"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get

```
LaTeX Warning: cref reference format for label type `sublisting' undefined on input line 35.

LaTeX Warning: cref reference format for label type `sublisting' undefined on input line 36.
```

Teach `cleveref` what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{sublisting}{sublisting}{sublistings}
\Crefname{sublisting}{Sublisting}{Sublistings}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{cpp}
void foo() {};
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Left figure caption}
    \label{lst:foo}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{minted}{cpp}
void bar() {};
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Right figure caption}
    \label{lst:bar}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Overall Caption}
  \label{lst:foo-bar}
\end{listing}

\begin{itemize}
\item Overall: \cref{lst:foo-bar}
\item Foo: \cref{lst:foo}
\item Bar: \cref{lst:bar}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want

```
\crefname{sublisting}{listing}{listings}
\Crefname{sublisting}{Listing}{Listings}
```

or

```
\crefname{sublisting}{Listing}{Listings}
```

if you always want uppercase. Take your pick.

Comment: That does what I want. Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. :)